# Using globbing in Fake

Tags: f#-fake

I'm converting a build script from Rake to Fake. I've got the following glob pattern's when trying to clean files (using the clean task from Rake)
'**/bin', '**/obj' What is the equivalent in Fake?

Answer (score 1):

```
!! "**/bin"
++ "**/obj"
|> DeleteDirs
```

or

```
!! "**/bin"
++ "**/obj"
|> CleanDirs
```

DeleteDirs deletes the directories, if they exist, CleanDirs recreates the given directories, if they don't exist